# How to interrupt voice assistant in python

Tags: python, speech-recognition, chatbot, voice, assistant

I am building a voice assistant that can tell stories. While the bot is telling stories I want to interrupt in between and ask it to stop or go backward or to end the story. I tried few ways, but they are not working I am not able to listen while it is speaking cause after the speaking part gets ended it goes to listening part.

Thanks in advance

Here is my code

```
while True:
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Talk")
        
        audio_text = r.listen(source)
        print("Time over, thanks")
        try:
            
            inp=r.recognize_google(audio_text, language = "en-IN")
            print("Text: "+inp)
        except:
            inp="sorry"
            print("Sorry, I did not get that")
    
    
    if inp.lower() == "quit":
        bot_voice("Ok bye see you later")
        break
    if inp.lower() == "sorry":
        bot_voice("Sorry, I did not get that")
    if (deter==0):
        y=-1
        deter=1
        for x in stories:
            m=x
            y=m.find(inp)
            if(y>-1):
                filename = 'Stories/data/'+x+'.txt'
                with open(filename) as f_in:
                    for line in f_in:
                        bot_voice(line)
                break
            
    
    else:
        results = model.predict([bag_of_words(inp, words)])
        results_index = numpy.argmax(results)
        tag = labels[results_index]

        for tg in data["intents"]:
            if tg['tag'] == tag:
                responses = tg['responses']
        reply=random.choice(responses)
        if(reply=='7417'):
            filename = "Stories/list.txt"
            bot_voice("I know quite a few stories, they are")
            with open(filename) as f_in:
                for x,line in enumerate(f_in):
                    bot_voice(line)
            bot_voice("which one you want")
            deter=0
        else:
            print("bot:",reply)
            bot_voice(reply)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible with the speech recognition you are using. This speech recognition takes input and doesn't provide output. With your output system, which I assume is something like pyttsx, would just read as it is told. You would require a stop system and you would need to do this with a machine learning-based program that is capable of conversations and can stop when told to stop and take keywords as commands.

I recommend Pytorch as a starter for Python Machine Learning. Here is an article on conversational AI.

[Article on Conversational AI with Pytorch](https://towardsdatascience.com/conversational-ai-chatbot-with-pretrained-transformers-using-pytorch-55b5e8882fd3)